# $db undefined, even after declaring it global

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I am declaring a PDO `$db` as so:

```
<?php
    $user = 'user';
    $pass = 'pass';

    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $user, $pass);
        $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<h1>' . $e->getMessage() . '</h1>';
    }
?>
```

and I'm getting these errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\path\page.php on line 40
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\path\functions.php:11 Stack trace:
>   '#0 C:\path\page.php(40): getSnippets(NULL, 1, 1) #1 {main} thrown in C:\path\functions.php
>   on line 11

This is how i am using my function, I'm even declaring it as a global variable as some others have done when i looked around:

```
function getSnippets($snippetID, $page) {
        global $db;
        try {
            $SQL = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM snippets WHERE id=:snippetID ORDER BY id LIMIT 10, :page');
            $SQL->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Set mode to fetch associative array
            $SQL->execute(array(
                ':snippetID' => $snippetID,
                ':page' => $page
            ));
            $result = $SQL->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) You don't concatenate strings with `+` in PHP, but with `.` 2) `$db` !== `$DBH` 3) Don't use global 4) Is the second code in another file? Do you include the file?

Comment: Try to pass it as parameter instead of using `global` anyway. Also make sure that your include is correct and works. (Simple test, put a `echo "HERE";` in the file, which you include. If you see it on the page good else not)

Comment: `getSnippets(NULL, 1, 1) ` are you passing 3 parameters to a function you've only defined with 2? `function getSnippets($snippetID, $page)` - you *can* do that but I'd expect to see something like `func_get_args()` if that's the case... you're not, inadvertently passing in a first parameter for `$db` as `NULL` are you?

Answer (score 0):

the page that contain "getSnippets" include the page where you have instanced the mysql connection?

Answer (score -1):

I had an underlying error of the PHP PDO driver not being uncommented in the php.ini file.

Thanks for the help!